# Are there rational solutions $r,s \in \mathbb{Q}$ to the equation $\tan^2(\pi r) + \tan^2(\pi s) = 1$

Tags: trigonometry, diophantine-equations, rationality-testing

I am seeking to understand the structure of solutions to the diophantine equation $$\tan^2(\pi r) + \tan^2(\pi s) = 1.$$ I am conjecturing that there are no rational solutions $r, s \in \mathbb{Q}$ to the equation satisfying both $\tan(\pi r) >0$ and $\tan(\pi s) >0$. (This is so we exclude "trivial" solutions such as $r = 1$ and $s = \frac{1}{4}$, which imply $\tan(\pi r) = 0$ and $\tan(\pi s) = 1$).

On the other hand, if there are "non-trivial" rational solutions, can the form of the solutions be characterized?

I have been unable to make progress on this, so thought I'd ask for any thoughts. Thank you!

Comment: Cross-multiplying the $\cos$ in both denominators makes me think of a trig identity for a sum of angles, but the RHS result doesn't look any easier at that point...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hint: in picture:

Blue is $y_1=tan^2(\pi x)$

Red is : $y=1- tan^2(\pi x)$

The soluyions are $x=0.2, 0.8, 1.2, 1.8,\cdot\cdot\cdot$

for graphing I let $\pi=3.14$ and $3.14\times x$ is in radian, if you want to calculate $y$ by hand using a calculator , you need to convert it to degrees:

$x=0.2\Rightarrow \pi x=3.14\times 0.2\approx 0.2\times 180^o=36^o$

$tan^2 36*o\approx 0.5$

$tan^2 36+tan^2 36=1$

I will work on a synthetic solution and will include  the result if I find something.

Update: For synthetic solutions we may write:

$tan^2 u=1-\frac{cos 2u}{cos^2 u}$ ; $u= \pi r$

$v=\pi s$

$$tan^2 (\pi r)=1- tan^2 (\pi s)$$

$$1-\frac{cos 2\pi r}{cos^2 (\pi r)}=1-\frac {sin^2(\pi s)}{cos^2 (\pi s)}$$

OR:

$$\frac{cos (2\pi r)}{cos^2 (\pi r)}=\frac {sin^2(\pi s)}{cos^2 (\pi s)}$$

The following system of equation is consistent:

$\begin{cases}cos (2\pi r)=sin^2(\pi s)\\cos^2(\pi r)=cos^2 (\pi s)\end{cases}$

which must be solved. $u=v\approx 36^o$ meets the condition of the original equation, other solutions  comes from equating the numerators:

$cos u=cos v\Rightarrow u+v=2k\pi$ or $u-v=2k\pi$

Which gives :

$u=0\rightarrow v=2k\pi\pm\frac {\pi}4$

$v=0\rightarrow u=2k\pi\pm\frac {\pi}4$

Also if $u=v$, as picture shows, then:

$u=v\approx 2k\pi\pm \frac {\pi}{5}$

Comment: Isn't it a mistake to consider $\pi=3.14$?

Comment: In fact, $\tan^2(36^\circ) = 0.52\dots$ so for the sum we do not get exactly $1$.

Comment: @GEdgar, I said approximately is $36^o$. The accurate magnitude must be calculated via synthetic solution.

Comment: @Piquito, I gave $\pi$ but GeoGebra did not respond.

Comment: There is a solution approximately $x=0.2$, namely $x=0.1959132760\dots$.  But it is probably irrational.  That is what we need to find out.

Comment: @Sirous: I think any computer can calculate algorithms with trascendental values (except several few operations). In Wolfram you can get the general solutions for $(r,s)$ and from these it seems no possibility of $s$ rational (non-trivial). Good luck.